# django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: <app>_connections_friends.connections_id

Tags: python, django

I have an User object

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, Base):
    username = models.CharField(db_index=True, null=False, unique=True, max_length=255)
    mobile = PhoneNumberField(db_index=True, null=False, unique=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

And I have the following Connections object

```
class Connections(Base):
    owner = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    friends = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='friend_set', symmetrical=True)
    followers = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="follower_set", symmetrical=False)
    followings = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name="following_set", symmetrical=False)
```

When I run the following line,

```
sender = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('sender_id'))
                    receiver = User.objects.get(id=kwargs.get('receiver_id'))

sender_connections, created = Connections.objects.get_or_create(owner=sender)
                    sender_connections.friends.add(receiver)
```

I get the following error,

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: no such column: <appname>_connections_friends.connections_id
```

I'm not sure what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: and you get this after you created the migrations and migrated?

Comment: After migration.